# Trouble deserializing json file via gson

Tags: java, gson

I have a json file

```
{
    "l": {
        "default_level": "...",
        "impl": "...",
        "levels": [
            ...,
            ...
        ]
    },
    "a": [
        {
            "format": "...",
            "filename": "...",
            "rotation": "...",
            "ls": [
                ...,
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Which i am trying to map to

```
public class ABC {

    private List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    private L lConfig = new L();

    // Gettters and Setters for aList and l

    public static class L {
        String default_level;
        String impl;

        List<String> levels = new ArrayList<>();

        // Gettters and Setters

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public static class A {
        String format;
        String filename;
        String rotation;

        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();

        // Getters and Setters

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

which is being deserialized by

```
public static BLAH load(String externalConfigFile) throws IOException {
    ABC config = null;

    Path path = Paths.get(externalConfigFile);
    if (Files.exists(path) || Files.isReadable(path)) {
        config = new Gson().fromJson(readFile(externalConfigFile), ABC.class);
    }

    return config;
}
```

Which, upon printing gives me

```
A[] 
L{default_level='null', impl='null', levels=[]}
```

Why is stuff not set?

Comment: Shouldn't the variable be named `l` to be mapped by Gson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is just the names of the attributes. In Gson, attributes' names must match the fields' names in the JSON.

So, you need to change the names of the attributes in the `ABC` class. Something like:

```
public class ABC {

    private List<A> a;
    private L l;

    //All the rest is okay...
}
```

Otherwise, you should use the annotation `@SerializedName`, like this:

```
@SerializedName("a")
private List<A> aList;
@SerializedName("l")
private L lConfig;
```

Comment: Right on the money! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array instead of a list here:

```
private A[] aList = {};
```

The List<A> will lose it's <A> during runtime and gson won't know where it should map the JSON array you're providing it.